# PHP - Image does not display on first page load, but does on second page load

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a PHP-based image viewer, and I've come across an odd issue. When I click an image to view it, the code says that it should show a resized version of the picture, which it has created and saved to the hard drive (so it doesn't need to remake the image more than once). However, it just shows a broken image and outputs an error complaining that the file it's looking for doesn't exist. If I refresh the page, the file does exist, and loads fine. What is going on here? I was under the impression that PHP was single-threaded

Below is the entirety of `image-view.php` (I have since deleted this code, as I made it for work, and it's not relevant to the problem I had)

Here is the `resize_image()` function from `functions.php`

```
//Return the path to a new or already existing resized version of the image you are looking for.
//I repeat: THIS FUNCTION RETURNS A PATH. IT DOES NOT RETURN AN ACTUAL IMAGE.
function resize_image($img, $imgPath, $width) {
    //error_log("!!!Calling resize_image({$img},{$imgName},{$width},{$imgDir})!!!");
    //Put the image in the .cache subdirectory.
    $imgName = end(explode("/",$imgPath));
    $imgDir = str_replace($imgName,"",$imgPath);
    $pathToThumbs = $imgDir . "/.cache/";
    $thumbWidth = $width;
    $thumbHeight = floor(imagesy($img) * ($width / imagesx($img)));
    $thumbName = get_resized_image_name($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $imgName);
    $resizedPath = "{$pathToThumbs}{$thumbName}";
    //Don't make a new image if it already exists.
    if (file_exists($pathToThumbs)) {
        if (file_exists($resizedPath)) {
            error_log("Resized image {$resizedPath} already exists. Exiting.");
            return $resizedPath;
        }
    }
    else {
        error_log("Cache folder does not exist. Creating.");
        $old_umask = umask(0);
        mkdir($pathToThumbs, 0777);
        umask($old_umask);
    }
    error_log("Resized image {$resizedPath} does not exist. Creating.");

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
    //This is the magic line right here. Create the thumbnail.
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, imagesx($img), imagesy($img));
    if (!file_exists($pathToThumbs)) {

    }
    imagepng($thumb, "{$pathToThumbs}{$thumbWidth}x{$thumbHeight}-{$imgName}");
    return $thumb;
}
```

Comment: Can you check if your functions return the same path for the first time image is created as when it finds out it already exists? Maybe for the first time the url is invalid

Comment: Can you show the entire PHP file? (not the functions, those are apparently working).  Typically this has to do with the order of the way that you call the procedures on the page

Comment: I just tried it. The first time, it returns "Resource ID 5." Why is it doing that?

Comment: Alright, I've added the entire image-view.php file to my post. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is because at the first call you are returning `$thumb` which is returned by `imagecreatetruecolor()` call.

The problem is it returns an image identifier, not file name. Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)

You can easily fix your code by changing the last line

```
//return $thumb;
return $resizedPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
imagepng($thumb, "{$pathToThumbs}{$thumbWidth}x{$thumbHeight}-{$imgName}");
return $thumb;
```

To:

```
$outPath = "{$pathToThumbs}{$thumbWidth}x{$thumbHeight}-{$imgName}";
imagepng($thumb, $outPath);
return $outPath;
```

Comment: That did the trick, but I replaced `$outpath` with `$resizedPath`, which already existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your first run, you return the `resource` that you pass in to the `imagepng` function. On second run, you return the path.

```
imagepng($thumb, "{$pathToThumbs}{$thumbWidth}x{$thumbHeight}-{$imgName}");
// $thumb is a resource.
return $thumb;
```

Make the function return the path in both cases.